# No spelling using Swiftkey and Android >4.0

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, autocorrect

There seems to be a bug with Jquery Mobile (1.2), Phonegap (2.2) and Swiftkey on Android >4.1 devices.

Normal `<input type="text"/>` and `<textarea>` works, but the Swiftkey keyboard does not provide spelling suggestions even though the attribute `autocomplete="on"` is present.

Anyone ever experienced this and know of a workaround?